# echo all row of a mysql_num_rows

Tags: php

I have the following php

```
  $q=mysql_query("select SMILES from GeoAndEnergies where Weight='".$data."' ") or die(mysql_error());
 $n=mysql_num_rows($q); //not mysql_fetch_row, as that does not return count but an array
 if($n>0)
 {
   $info=mysql_fetch_row($q);
    echo $info[0];
  }
  else {
   echo "molecule not find";
  }
```

I would like to echo not just $info[0] but $info[0]+"<"+ $info[1] + "<" .... + $info[n], what would be the correct syntax?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `while` loop to fetch all rows

```
$q=mysql_query("select SMILES from GeoAndEnergies where Weight='".$data."' ") or die(mysql_error());
 $n=mysql_num_rows($q); 

 if($n>0)
 {
   $val='';
   while($info=mysql_fetch_row($q))
    {
      if($val!='')
          $val.=' < ';
      $val.= $info[0];
    }
 }
  else {
   $val= "molecule not find";
  }
 echo $val;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are just printing one, so put it in a loop. I suggest:

```
$q=mysql_query("select SMILES from GeoAndEnergies where Weight='".$data."' ") or die(mysql_error());
$n=mysql_num_rows($q); //not mysql_fetch_row, as that does not return count but an array
$str = '';
if($n>0)
{
    while ($info=mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
        $str .= $info['SMILES'] .'<';
    }
echo substr($str, 0, -1);
} else {
    echo "molecule not found";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problems solution is Below
using the echo '';print_r($info);die;
Or other wise using for loop you will get all the data which you will want.

Comment: I would like to add the separator "<" bitween elements.

Comment: Yes Like this echo '<pre>';print_r($info);die;

Comment: to add the separator "<" use the function `implode("<",$info);`